# How to use "if" to overcome data are essentially constant error in r?

Tags: r

I need to compare the bacterial gene expression abundance between control and disease samples. I have a large data set which has been read by R. It contains 58,000 rows which are the different genes, and 6 columns. The first three columns represent the values in control whilst the remaining three are from diseased patients.

The data is a matrix and all values are numeric.

I am new to R, and I am trying to figure out how to include an "if" to prevent the error "data are essentially constant", which I am assuming is happening because a lot of the gene expression values are the same in both disease and control group ( some of the gene expression values are 0 in both groups too).

The code I am using is as follows;

```r
pvalues <- apply(finalgenecount, 1, function(currRow)
    { t.test(currRow[4:6], currRow[1:3])$p.value } )
```

I basically need to find which genes are most abundant in the disease vs control, and was going to use a foldchange to identify what genes are increased in the disease group based on the pvalues from the above code.

I am struggling to include an "if" correctly to overcome my error.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. 
Thank-you

exact error message:

```
Error in t.test.default(currRow[4:6], currRow[1:3]) : 
  data are essentially constant is the error message.
```

Comment: Hi, it's do-able, so you want to have a NA if it cannot be tested? A slightly off-topic suggestion would be you can try something like DESeq or edgeR? gives you more power

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the best way to address this is to write the function separately, then use the `apply` function.

First, we have the reprex data.

```
dat <- structure(c(37L, 1L, 187L, 97L, 162L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
                   0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                 .Dim = c(6L, 6L), 
                 .Dimnames = list( c("gene1_36040_cov_12.4365_1", 
                                     "gene2_36040_cov_12.4365_3", 
                                     "gene3_32139_cov_10.3119_1", 
                                     "gene4_32139_cov_10.3119_2", 
                                     "gene5_32139_cov_10.3119_3", 
                                     "gene6_27992_cov_10.5976_1" ), 
                                   c("SRR527345", "SRR527312", "SRR527312", 
                                     "SRR52324", "SRR525625", "SRR53526")))
```

Then we develop a function that tests the 4th-6th rows again the 1-3rd row. If the t-test fails, it will throw an NA rather than an error.

```
you_function <- function(currRow){

  res <- try(t.test(currRow[4:6], currRow[1:3])$p.value)

  if(grepl(pattern = "Error", x = res)){ 
    return(NA)
  } else {
    res
  }

}
```

This function uses a `try` which returns an error if the function fails and the result if there is a result. Now you can apply this function

```
out <- apply(dat, 1,you_function )
```

We will also name this new vector based on the column names in the data.

```
names(out) <- colnames(dat)

out
```

Which will give us:

```
SRR527345 SRR527312 SRR527312  SRR52324 SRR525625  SRR53526 
0.3923287 0.4226497 0.4134629 0.3881068 0.4226497 0.4226497
```

Now we can add a threshold and only return those gene names that meet some threshold. Because the above values are mostly >.4, I will set the threshold to this level for illustrative purposes. Should you want to drop the threshold to 0.05 you can.

```
p_thresh <- 0.4

names(out)[out <= p_thresh]
```

Which will give us:

```
[1] "SRR527345" "SRR52324"
```

Testing this on "bad" data where the same value is repeated looks like the following:

```
bad <- matrix(rep(1, 36), ncol = 6)

out <- apply(bad, 1,you_function )

out
```

Which outputs the following. You'll still get a message, but

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the above. I now have an error which says Error in classes(res) : could not find function "classes".

Comment: Sorry try now. Should be class rather than classes

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am now trying to identify the genes whereby there is a significant difference in expression (p < 0.05), however, I can use code to see how many there are. Not too sure whether to use a grep or  if function to get the names of the genes ( which are in the rows), with a p value less than 0.05. When I try to do it, it returns the gene names with false as a p value and this isn't right.

Comment: @Hugh169 try this now

Comment: @hugh169 no problem. If the solution works please accept it as the solution so others know that it is a valid solution.

Comment: I'm still trying to find ways to get the genes with a p value < 0.05, as it does not recognize out at the moment, which is the error I am getting in R.

Comment: @Hugh169, if possible do `dput(head(data)` where `data` is your data. We can better troubleshoot if we have this.

Comment: I did the above, and here is the output in the R console

Comment: structure(c(37L, 1L, 187L, 97L, 162L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("gene1_36040_cov_12.4365_1", "gene2_36040_cov_12.4365_3", 
    "gene3_32139_cov_10.3119_1", "gene4_32139_cov_10.3119_2", 
    "gene5_32139_cov_10.3119_3", "gene6_27992_cov_10.5976_1"
    ), c("SRR527345", "SRR527312", "SRR527312", "SRR52324", 
    "SRR525625", "SRR53526")))

Comment: @Hugh169 give it a look now. I added it with your data.

Comment: I have tried again, and I'm sorry to say it still doesn't work, as it still says that the data are essentially constant, even with the "if".

Comment: @Hugh169 finally, finally, fixed. It still prints that there is an error, but it returns an `NA` as shown above

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are applying a t.test to two vectors, the two triplets per line. If either set has 3 equal values, it throws an error.

Without your data, it's hard to hand tailor a good solution, but you could select only the rows where these two sets of elements 1:3 and 4:6 have at least one element different from each other.

```
selection_vector <- !(
finalgenecount[1,] == finalgenecount[2,] | 
finalgenecount[1,] == finalgenecount[3,] | 
finalgenecount[2,] == finalgenecount[3,] | 
finalgenecount[4,] == finalgenecount[5,] | 
finalgenecount[4,] == finalgenecount[6,] | 
finalgenecount[5,] == finalgenecount[6,]
)
```

Basically you'd need to use only the line where no values on either set match. Hence the "!" to reverse the logical check on any cases where a pair of columns on either set is true. It's possible to make this filter in other ways, but this method doesn't require any packages.

```
pvalues <- apply(finalgenecount[selection_vector ,], 1, function(currRow)
  {
  t.test(currRow[4:6], currRow[1:3])$p.value})
```